# Showing integral is non-negative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to show that some function is convex. It all comes down to showing that some integral is bounded below by zero. Here is the problem:

Let $\kappa,\phi,\psi>0$ be real numbers. Let $f,F:[0,T]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be some function where $\int_0^T f(s) \, ds < \infty$, and where $T>0$. Let's also define $F(t) = F_0 + \int_0^t f(s) \, ds$ where $F_0\in\mathbb{R}$.

Assuming all of the above, I want to find the necessary requirements on $\phi,\Psi,\kappa$ so that
$$
\int_0^T  \left\{ \kappa \,\left(f(t)\right)^2 + \phi \, \left( F(t) \right)^2 + 2\Psi \, f(t) F(t) \right\} \, dt
\geq 0
\;.
$$ 
I know that a sufficient condition is for $\sqrt{\kappa\phi}\geq\Psi$... Are there necessary conditions on these constants? Ideally I'd like to avoid requirements on $f,F_0$.

Comment: Since $$\int_0^T 2f(t)F(t)\,dt = F(T)^2 - F(0)^2,$$ we can choose $\kappa, \phi, \Psi, F_0$ in such a way that your integral becomes negative, unless $\int_0^T f(t)\,dt = 0$.

Comment: I think that as long as $\kappa,\phi,\Psi>0$ this is not true. You'll have to give me a concrete example / proof for me to believe you.

Comment: @DanielFischer you were right. I actually managed to find a counterexample:
$f=\sin{t}^2$, $F_0 = -1000$, $\kappa=\phi=10^{-4}$, $T=\Psi=1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I changed the problem slightly.